# Semi-complete partites

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is there a name for regular bipartite graphs where each partite has the semi-completeness property (that is, for each two vertices $i$,$v$ in the partite $V$, there is a path $\{i,w,v\}$, where $w$ belongs to the other partite), but not necessarily the whole graph?

Edit: I am not looking for graphs that satisfy this property, I am wondering whether this property has a name.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not necessarily the whole graph"?

Comment: I mean that the graph does not need to be semi-complete. Obviously, if it is, then the partites will have the property. But it is possible for the partites to have the property, but not the graph in total.

Comment: So are you asking for a name for regular bipartite graphs with the property that every two vertices $i,v$ in the same partite set have at least one common neighbour?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering whether such graphs have a given name

Comment: Not really. There can be 2 vertices not belonging in the same partite that do not have a common neighbour, thus the diameter in that case would be 3.

Comment: Of course you're right. The diameter is definitely at most $3$ though.